# Stopping Android Location Updates without listener object?

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm trying to stop location updates in my android app onPause, and I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to stop them. I know the code to stop is something along the lines of:

```
mLocManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerObject);
mLocManager = null;
```

But I don't have a locationListenerObject as far as I know! Here's the code for getting location at the moment:

```
LocationManager lManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

lManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1, new LocationListener()

Location location = lManager.getLastKnownLocation(lManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
```

How might I stop this from running?

Comment: I dont see where you even requested location updates so you shouldnt be getting location changes anyway

Comment: The last line gets the last known location. Then I do location.getLatitude(); etc.

Comment: that is not requesting location updates, that is just getting the last stored location

Comment: Check this out - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#StartListening

Comment: tyczj - My bad - found where my locationListener was. See edit... And I know what to do - define a global locationListener object and pass that as an argument for lManager.removeUpdates...

Comment: The question is - how might I set that 'new LocationListener()' as a variable that I can reference?